# Send mail from appengine with application firewall activated

Tags: php, cron, google-cloud-platform, sendgrid, google-app-engine-php

I am developing a microservice with PHP and appengine. I achieved to send emails with sendgrid. For security reasons the firewall was activate, but then the email service did not work enymore.

I know that the firewall its only for incoming traffic in this case, but that was the only thing that i change, and of course if i shut down the firewall the application works.

UPDATED

The appengiene microservice is call from a cron service.

Comment: I could fix it! when an appengine service is used and this is called from a cron job with activated firewall a rule has to be added to allow the ip 0.1.0.1(Standard enviroment) https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/creating-firewalls

Comment: If you solved the issue, please post the comment as an answer (well-explained, for other users). In this case it is perfectly ok to [answer your own questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: Thanks @AniaRudzińska

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could fix it! when an App Engine service is used and this is called from a cron job with activated firewall a rule has to be added to allow the ip 0.1.0.1 (Standard environment)

For more information see the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/creating-firewalls)

> To control the access of requests from other App Engine apps or services, you might need to create rules to accommodate the IP addresses that are   used for service-to-service communication. If your app communicates with  other apps or services in App Engine, you must consider how to handle 
>   requests from the following IP addresses:
>
> - Job requests from the Cron service:
>
>   - Requests received in the standard environment: 0.1.0.1
>   - Requests received in the flexible environment: 0.1.0.1 and 10.0.0.1